# Affine cipher encryption in c++

Tags: c++

I think this c++ code should work for encrypting in affine cipher. But the output shows strange characters instead of normal alphabets. I don't understand why.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Enter string: "; 
char whatever[20];
gets (whatever);
char something [20]; 
int a; 
int b = 8; 
int m = 26; 
int coprimetest;

for (a=2;coprimetest!=1;a++)
{ 
  for (int i=1;i<=a&&i<=m;i++)  
  {  
    if (a%i==0 && m%i ==0) coprimetest=i;  
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(whatever); i++)
    something [i]= (char)((((a * whatever[i]-65) + b) % m)+65);

for (int i=0; i < sizeof(something); i++)
    cout << something[i];

}
```

Comment: This is probably not the issue, but on the first loop you're checking `coprimetest`'s value before initializing it. This yields undefined behavior, which might be exploited by the compiler for some over-aggressive optimization.

Comment: testing your code I'm not experiencing your issue: does the code prints the strange chars for every input or for some specific one? the uninitialized var might be partially responsible, if for any reason it moves the range of the ascii value outside the printable char range

Comment: @Ayato there is also another big issue in your code: you are not initializing the buffers `something` and `whatever` That means that given the same input you are getting different outputs, and I guess this is not the expected behavior looking at the code

Comment: but i've initialized all arrays and variables...
    char something [20];

Answer (score 0):

After initializing your variable coprimetest to 0 and running this a few times I notice that for the length of the string that I enter into the console using `std::cin >> whatever;` I am getting changed characters for all characters in that string up to the first white space character. So if I type in `"Hello"` I'm getting `"XJLLX<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"` as output to the console from the for loop. Now if I try `"Hello World"` I'm getting the same exact output. If I try `"HelloWorld"` my output is now `"XJLLXFXJLF<<<<<<<<<<"`. The values `"1234567890"` gives me `"JNRVZDHLPF<<<<<<<<<<"`. The values `"abcdefghijklmnopqrst"` gives `"TXBFJNRVZDHLPTXBFJNF"`. The values `"uvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLM"` gives `"VZDHLPVZDHLPTXBFJNRV"`. The only thing with entering exactly 20 characters into the string is that it does print successfully but after my next line of code that gives me another message to `"Press Any Key To Quit"` which is coming from one of my utility functions; the program does crash giving me an error message of: `Run-Time Failure #2 - Stack around the variable "whatever" was corrupted.` as this is coming from MSVS2015 CE. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: thankyou for explaining, i get it,i'll have to enter exactly 20 characters.

Comment: @Ayato If you enter exactly 20 characters it crashes the program with a  runtime failure. I don't know if it has to do with using iostream's cin & cout when working with char[] but you may want to consider to use a string instead and just iterate over the string the same way as the char[]. This way it can incorporate blank spaces as well.